# How to get a list of all domains?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, directoryentry

I'm trying to get all domains that are available in the Windows Login dialog (in the Domain dropdown).

I've tried the following code but it only returns the domain I am logged into.  Am I missing something?

```
StringCollection domainList = new StringCollection();
try
{
    DirectoryEntry en = new DirectoryEntry();
    // Search for objectCategory type "Domain"
    DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(en, "objectCategory=Domain");
    SearchResultCollection coll = srch.FindAll();
    // Enumerate over each returned domain.
    foreach (SearchResult rs in coll)
    {
        ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = rs.Properties;
        foreach( object domainName in resultPropColl["name"])
        {
            domainList.Add(domainName.ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Trace.Write(ex.Message);
}
return domainList;
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but you don't appear to ever use DirectoryEntry en.

Comment: Sorry, code fixed up.  Still the same result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll

```
using (var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
{
    foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(domain.Name);
        domain.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to add "using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;" to pickup the Forest objects.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx). You'll find a simple code snippet to enumerate domains in the current forest.