# How to instantiate a DirectoryEntry object with a domain?

Tags: c#, active-directory, dns

I have a list of `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain` objects gotten via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596419/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-domains/2597342#2597342) method.  How do I know instantiate a `DirectoryEntry` object with this Domain object?  The syntax seems to escape me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Domain.GetDirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getdirectoryentry.aspx) method?  This will give you a `DirectoryEntry` that represents the root of the domain.

Comment: You are a freaking genius.  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks.